# Printing gives me a memory address on a class list rather than a specific STR

Tags: inheritance, python-2.7

It may be a basic question because I started learning self-taught with the book [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.pdf). And there's an exercise that I don't quiet follow why is not printing the card string, rather it does print a memory address.

Here is the whole code:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    '''Represents a standard playing card'''

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    suit_names = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    rank_names = [None, 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank], Card.suit_names[self.suit])

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        t1= self.suit, self.rank
        t2 = other.suit, other.rank
        return cmp(t1, t2)

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1,14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for card in self.cards:
            res.append(str(card))
        return '\n'.join(res)

    def pop_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def sort(self):
        self.cards.sort()

    def move_card(self, hand, num):
        for i in range(num):
            hand.add_card(self.pop_card())

    def deal_hands(self, _cards, hands):
        handsdeal = []
        for i in range(hands):
            hand = Hand()
            self.move_card(hand, _cards)
            handsdeal.append(hand.cards)
        return handsdeal

class Hand(Deck):

    def __init__(self, label=''):
        self.cards = []
        self.label = label
```

Let me explain:

I call the method deal_hands with a deck j (j = Deck()) and _cards= 2 and hands= 3. The result is a list of Hand but when I print that list I get list with list as intended but with ugly memory address as elements. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

**str** should be used by Hand too, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the list to print something other than the instance information you need to implement __repr__ on your Card class.  The list container uses this function instead of __str__ to get the string representations for the objects it contains.  This is mainly for debugging purposes and should uniquely identify the object.

So...First I added the following to your Card class.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank], Card.suit_names[self.suit])
```

Then I used the following at the bottom of the file to generate output.

```
# Printing the whole list (which uses __repr__)
j=Deck()
foo = j.deal_hands(2,3)
print foo

# Printing the lists (which uses __str__)
for hand in foo:
  for card in hand:
    print card
```

My output

```
$ python test.py 
[[King of Spades, Queen of Spades], [Jack of Spades, 10 of Spades], [9 of Spades, 8 of Spades]]
King of Spades
Queen of Spades
Jack of Spades
10 of Spades
9 of Spades
8 of Spades
```

Update: Just thought it might also be worth mentioning the pprint module as it's handy when wanting to get nice output of complex structures in python.  Try adding the following under the nested for loops I had above.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(foo)
```

Outputs

```
[   [King of Spades, Queen of Spades],
    [Jack of Spades, 10 of Spades],
    [9 of Spades, 8 of Spades]]
```